# Splicing Amount of Data From Text File Into Array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to splice my data from my text-file and instead of returning a specific column it returns all my data. It might possibly be a `syntax error` but I can't seem to google what I'm doing wrong.

For example I have:

```
x   y
1   2
2   4
3   6
```

and after splicing I receive

```
'1 2\n 2 4\n 3 6\n'
```

in the variable I'm storing instead of just

```
'1 2 3'
```

Which is what I want

I've been trying to do this:

```
data = open('file').read()

x = data[1:][2:]
```

Comment: The code from the question should run fine. You get the complete file except the first 3 charaters. Is this what you're after? Please read [ask] and edit your question with a clear problem description - what do you expect, what do you get, in how far do they differ?

Comment: well, perhaps you can popup the first two elements then loop out and check if the counter is odd then it's belonging to x and if it's even then it's related to y

Answer (score 0):

Reading in

```
x y
1 2
2 4
3 6
```

with

```
data = open('file').read()
```

results in `data` being the string `"x y\n1 2\n 2 4\n 3 6\n"`. From that string you first select all but the first character (`data[1:]`) and from that again all but the first two characters (`data[1:][2:]`). This results in the first three characters beeing omitted,

```
"x y\n1 2\n 2 4\n 3 6\n"
```

The result is hence expected.

In order to get a "column" you would first need to define a column in some way. Usually, one would use some tool like numpy to read in such files.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('file', skiprows=1)
print(data)
x = data[:,0]
print(x)
```

This prints the complete numpy array

```
[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 2.  4.]
 [ 3.  6.]]
```

and then the first column of it,

```
[ 1.  2.  3.]
```